# The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

Tags: django, azure

I have a site deployed on azure with django. I have been working on the site for about 6 months and it was working fine. Today all of a sudden the site is not working any more.

The only output I am getting is - "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

I have the same django code working perfectly on localhost. My azure account has 2 django sites running. Each site is deployed from 2 separate branches from a git repo. Both of them are down.

I tried deploying earlier deployments on azure. it is still showing the same error.

I have also tried setting debug to true on production server. Same results. It seems django is not even being loaded.

My azure account shows a lot of "html server error", when I check under the monitor tab for the site.

What is the problem and how do I solve it? Is a django not loading problem or an azure problem? How do I debug this?

Edit - error log from ftp - logfiles/http/rawlogs

```
# date time s-sitename cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
2013-07-19 13:20:30 MAKEYSTREET GET /robots.txt X-ARR-LOG-ID=dbb6383f-5342-4fe4-a419-e3f5f373a8f8 80 - 66.249.74.139 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) - - www.makeystreet.com 500 0 0 245 416 3484
2013-07-19 13:34:28 MAKEYSTREET GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=b4c37c5c-46b3-4ff5-9ae7-e0f18f04b404 80 - 10.21.91.242 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+i686)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Ubuntu+Chromium/28.0.1500.52+Chrome/28.0.1500.52+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=cf6d46f9fadcc9b088669ec23467baf056a50376566d6aacdbea46e06b6acfa5;+WAWebSiteSID=6c2bf64764594b7ca90e2b539b89b9e6;+sessionid=rhvhu9ibb814v1vwqe3nahkkt1lw0yvu;+csrftoken=gO1x5Vm6kzDRKhmbyjbUuVqWKLUjW3Qy;+_ga=GA1.2.1129966823.1374156576 - makeystreet.com 500 0 0 269 897 3546
2013-07-19 13:34:28 MAKEYSTREET GET /favicon.ico X-ARR-LOG-ID=d918daf9-815e-4ef7-8360-525c9c31506c 80 - 10.21.91.242 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+i686)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Ubuntu+Chromium/28.0.1500.52+Chrome/28.0.1500.52+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=cf6d46f9fadcc9b088669ec23467baf056a50376566d6aacdbea46e06b6acfa5;+WAWebSiteSID=6c2bf64764594b7ca90e2b539b89b9e6;+sessionid=rhvhu9ibb814v1vwqe3nahkkt1lw0yvu;+csrftoken=gO1x5Vm6kzDRKhmbyjbUuVqWKLUjW3Qy;+_ga=GA1.2.1129966823.1374156576 - makeystreet.com 500 0 0 269 864 93
2013-07-19 14:04:47 MAKEYSTREET GET /robots.txt X-ARR-LOG-ID=1b516136-4a39-4543-b9a4-540ce1fce959 80 - 66.249.74.139 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) - - www.makeystreet.com 500 0 0 245 416 3515
2013-07-19 14:05:54 MAKEYSTREET GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=7dc870f8-a7d4-4701-8b75-042789a362cf 80 - 122.166.237.111 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:22.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/22.0 - - www.makeystreet.com 500 0 0 245 440 187
2013-07-19 14:05:54 MAKEYSTREET GET /favicon.ico X-ARR-LOG-ID=64681a43-c47e-4aea-982d-bd3dace9b19e 80 - 122.166.237.111 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:22.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/22.0 ARRAffinity=cf6d46f9fadcc9b088669ec23467baf056a50376566d6aacdbea46e06b6acfa5;+WAWebSiteSID=2e0ff00f9fd84e28ac6b757c93b43b23 - www.makeystreet.com 500 0 0 245 595 62
2013-07-19 14:06:10 MAKEYSTREET GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=db1870ec-3b2a-4449-ac13-05ab67ffa212 80 - 122.166.237.111 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:22.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/22.0 ARRAffinity=cf6d46f9fadcc9b088669ec23467baf056a50376566d6aacdbea46e06b6acfa5;+WAWebSiteSID=2e0ff00f9fd84e28ac6b757c93b43b23 - www.makeystreet.com 500 0 0 245 573 109
2013-07-19 14:21:55 MAKEYSTREET GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=4e72fbec-ff2e-4068-b9fe-0a536718e8c7 80 - 10.21.91.242 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+i686)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Ubuntu+Chromium/28.0.1500.52+Chrome/28.0.1500.52+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=cf6d46f9fadcc9b088669ec23467baf056a50376566d6aacdbea46e06b6acfa5;+WAWebSiteSID=6c2bf64764594b7ca90e2b539b89b9e6;+sessionid=rhvhu9ibb814v1vwqe3nahkkt1lw0yvu;+csrftoken=gO1x5Vm6kzDRKhmbyjbUuVqWKLUjW3Qy;+_ga=GA1.2.1129966823.1374156576 - makeystreet.com 500 0 0 245 887 3515
2013-07-19 14:21:56 MAKEYSTREET GET /favicon.ico X-ARR-LOG-ID=ee05ce88-08cc-4837-94a4-4ef0326a46be 80 - 10.21.91.242 Mozilla/5.0+(X11;+Linux+i686)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Ubuntu+Chromium/28.0.1500.52+Chrome/28.0.1500.52+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=cf6d46f9fadcc9b088669ec23467baf056a50376566d6aacdbea46e06b6acfa5;+WAWebSiteSID=6c2bf64764594b7ca90e2b539b89b9e6;+sessionid=rhvhu9ibb814v1vwqe3nahkkt1lw0yvu;+csrftoken=gO1x5Vm6kzDRKhmbyjbUuVqWKLUjW3Qy;+_ga=GA1.2.1129966823.1374156576 - makeystreet.com 500 0 0 269 864 124
```

Comment: have you looked at your server error logs ?

Comment: I looked at the error log. I am not sure if I am looking at the right file. I got it from ftp logfiles/http/rawlogs

Comment: Is it possible for you to set DEBUG=True in the settings of one of your apps and navigate to it with a non-public address? You don't want debug=true on a live site, so make sure it's publically unreachable at it's normal address (take down for maintenance).

Comment: Hey Josh, I donno how to set debug=true on a non public site. But even on a public site, DEBUG=true is not yielding any results. Its looks as if django is not loading at all.